# Spring Cloud Function / propagates request to Function

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I'm new to Java and to Spring, and I'm not sure how this example code is working in that "SpringBootRequestHandler" implements the AWS RequestHandler, and also "propagates the request to our function".

The example is found here: https://dzone.com/articles/run-code-with-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda

I've reviewed this code for awhile - and I'm not connecting the dots on how the UppercaseFunction gets invoked via the UppercaseFunctionHandler.

I'll apologize in advance if this isn't the right place to ask this question, but I'm not sure where else I can ask for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So `UppercaseFunctionHandler` extends `SpringBootRequestHandler` which extends `SpringFunctionInitializer` which is where the magic happens.

[When a request is received,](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/a973b678f1d4d6f703a530e2d9e071b6d650567f/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/SpringBootRequestHandler.java#L42) the handler will attempt to initialize the spring context.
[During initialization, it will look up the property `function.name`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/a973b678f1d4d6f703a530e2d9e071b6d650567f/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/SpringFunctionInitializer.java#L92) defined in the [`application.properties`](https://github.com/laxika/spring-cloud-function-aws-example/blob/5f16294a37c0c0766d1f479f74f4260130967e35/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1) which is the name of [function component](https://github.com/laxika/spring-cloud-function-aws-example/blob/5f16294a37c0c0766d1f479f74f4260130967e35/src/main/java/com/morethanheroic/uppercase/UppercaseFunction.java#L11) bean that would of been discovered during component scanning.

So in summary there is a lot of indirection going on here, and it's certainly hard to understand without digging into the framework code and having a bit of knowledge about the way spring works.

Comment: Awesome! I was wondering where the connection is made.  I saw the class annotation but didnt know about application prop. Thanks!